# Removing Animation From UINavigationController Pushed Unwind?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uistoryboardsegue

I have a simple push segue from one view controller to another. I want both segues (original and unwind to be unanimated).

In the attached playground, specifying false for the segue does, indeed remove the PUSH animation, but not the UNWIND animation.

Is there a way to remove the implicit animation in the UNWIND segue?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class SourceViewController : UIViewController {
    @objc func goDestination(_: Any) {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(DestinationViewController(), animated: false)
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        navigationItem.title = "SOURCE"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(goDestination(_:)))
    }
}

class DestinationViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        navigationItem.title = "DESTINATION"
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SourceViewController())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those animations are fully customizable from the UINavigationControllerDelegate, check out the first "Supporting Custom Transition Animations" method

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate

Some details here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWckfDNUJVY
at 23 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! That may be what I need. I’ll give it a go, tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm greenchecking @glotcha's answer. It led me to [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@ludvigeriksson/custom-interactive-uinavigationcontroller-transition-animations-in-swift-4-a4b5e0cefb1e), which led me to this solution (I really wanted a fade transition):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TransitioningAnimatorInOut: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    var presenting: Bool = false
    
    func transitionDuration(using: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval { 0.75 }
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from),
              let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else { return }

        let container = transitionContext.containerView
        
        if presenting {
            container.addSubview(toView)
            toView.alpha = 0.0
        } else {
            container.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
        if self.presenting {
                toView.alpha = 1.0
            } else {
                fromView.alpha = 0.0
            }
        }) { _ in
            let success = !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            if !success {
                toView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
        }
    }
    
    init(presenting inPresenting: Bool) { presenting = inPresenting }
}

extension UINavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    public func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        if operation == .push {
            return TransitioningAnimatorInOut(presenting: true)
        } else {
            return TransitioningAnimatorInOut(presenting: false)
        }
    }
}

class SourceViewController : UIViewController {
    @objc func goDestination(_: Any) {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(DestinationViewController(), animated: true)
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view?.backgroundColor = .yellow
        navigationItem.title = "SOURCE"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(goDestination(_:)))
    }
}

class DestinationViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view?.backgroundColor = .red
        navigationItem.title = "DESTINATION"
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SourceViewController())
```

Comment: Nice! That API (as well as the interactive variant and UIPresentationController) are a real rabbit hole, well done for getting what you needed :)